# SQL check for unique column combination entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table "`Pcategory`", with the following 4 columns and `PCategoryID` is my primary key,

```
Pcategory Table         
PCategoryID(PK) |TermID (FK)|SubCategoryID (FK)|CategoryID(FK)
```

PK -> Primary key
FK -> Foreign key

Please let me know how to write a SQL query to check the table has a unique combination of foriengn keys `TermID` (FK)|`SubCategoryID` (FK)|`CategoryID` (FK).

(i.e) I would be needing a list of duplicate records if any from the table with the combination of these 3 foriegn keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope the below is what you are looking for :

```
select termid,subcategoryid,categoryid,count(1)
from pcategory
group by termid,subcategoryid,categoryid 
having count(1) > 1
```